# Database table contents wont appear when I use hibernate class

Tags: hibernate

The POJO class was created correctly along with the Util class.Here are the controller and model.dao classes:

```
package model.dao;

import java.util.List;
import model.pojo.Device;
import model.util.HibernateUtil;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;

public class DeviceDAO {
    public static List<Device> layDS(){
        List<Device> lst=null;
        try{
            Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            String hql="from device";
            Query query;
            query = session.createQuery(hql);
            lst=query.list();
            session.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    return lst;}
}
//end of deviceDAO
```

Now the DeviceController class:

```
package controller;

import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import model.dao.DeviceDAO;
import model.pojo.Device;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;

public class DeviceController implements Controller{

    @Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest hsr, HttpServletResponse hsr1) throws Exception {
ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView("devices");
    try{
        List<Device> lst=DeviceDAO.layDS();
        mv.addObject("devices",lst);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mv;}

}
//end of deviceController class
```

Here is the devices.jsp file:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Device List!</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th><th>latitude</th><th>longitude</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach var="device" items="${devices}">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <c:out value="${device.getDevId()}"></c:out>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <c:out value="${device.getLatitude()}"></c:out>
                    </td>
                     <td>
                        <c:out value="${device.getLongitude()}"></c:out>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>

//end of device.jsp file
```

Here are the two additions I made in the dispatcher-servlet.xml class:

```
<bean class="controller.DeviceController" id="DeviceController" />
 <prop key="devices.jsp">DeviceController</prop>
```

I have tested the connection with the database and it is working fine but I am not sure why the contents of the table in the database are not being displayed.

Kindly help me figure out what am I doing wrong!

Comment: Well, for a start, your HQL query is invalid. Your entity is named `Device`, not `device`. Use your debugger, don't ignore exceptions, if you open sessions, close them in a finally block, as explained in the documentation.

Comment: I changed the name to Device, still no data is displayed no exception occurs,debugger does not show any error either

Comment: A debugger is not used to show errors. It allows stepping through the code step by step, and thus see what is actually executed, what the query actually returns, etc. You first need to find out where the problem is: is it a problem with the query, with the JSP, with the controller, with the database settings, with the database data?